# about facebook sdk in ios and taggable_friends endpoint

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using facebook SDK4.0 in ios i am trying to retrieve logged in user's friendlist by using taggable_friends. I have been able to achieve that.The whole friend list is showing but the problem is with the names. In the returning dictionary some names are showing weird numbers. I've found the reason as well, because the names are of language other than english, most of them are of bengali.Is there any way to get the names in their respective languages?? I am adding the method and snippet of what weird names i am getting.Please help if u know something of this sort!!please!!

```
   -(void) getMineFriends
 {
NSDictionary *limitDictionary = [NSDictionary     dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"600",@"limit", nil];

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me/taggable_friends" parameters:limitDictionary HTTPMethod:@"GET"]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"friends = %@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]  );
}];
```

}

Here is an example of the weird name: name = "\U0995\U09be\U099c\U09c0 \U09a4\U09c1\U09b7\U09be\U09b0";

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.The problem was that i was accessing the result with object key "data" but when i initialized an array of dictionary with  result with object key "data" and then i accessed the name with object key "name" and it came out good.sorry for the inconvenience :P

```
        -(void) getMineFriends
        {
          NSDictionary *limitDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"600",@"limit", nil];

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me/taggable_friends" parameters:limitDictionary HTTPMethod:@"GET"]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *friendsarray = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    for (NSDictionary *friend in friendsarray) {
        NSLog(@"i have a friend named %@",[friend objectForKey:@"name"]);
    }
}];
```

}
here is the changed code :D